How to get the EFI Stub included on NixOS?
I have following Nix file for building a Linux kernel:
{ pkgs, lib, config, ... }:

{
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [ llvm_18 clang_18 lld_18 ];
  boot.kernelPackages = let
      llvm = pkgs.llvmPackages_18;
      localversion = "-nitrous4";
      linux_nitrous_pkg = { buildLinux, ... } @ args:

        buildLinux (args // rec {
          version = "6.11.0";
          modDirVersion = "${version}${localversion}";

          src = fetchTarball {
            url = "https://gitlab.com/xdevs23/linux-nitrous/-/archive/v6.11.0-3/linux-nitrous-v6.11.0-3.tar.gz";
            sha256 = "0f0rpxxssknqr7l73hqrq4ad20zlpv6h41j8n85w4fkz5s7z118j";
          };
#          defconfig = "nitrous_defconfig";
          allowImportFromDerivation = true;
          stdenv = pkgs.overrideCC llvm.stdenv (llvm.stdenv.cc.override { inherit (llvm) bintools; });
          extraMakeFlags = [
            "LLVM=1"
          ];

          structuredExtraConfig = with lib.kernel; {
            MNATIVE_AMD = yes;
            LOCALVERSION_AUTO = no;
            NTSYNC = yes;
            DEBUG_LIST = lib.mkForce no;
            LIST_HARDENED = yes;
            LATENCYTOP = no;
            BCACHEFS_FS = module;
            DRM_XE = module;
            DEBUG_INFO_BTF = lib.mkForce no;
            PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY = yes;
            CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_PERFORMANCE_O3 = yes;
            KVM = yes;
            LTO_CLANG_THIN = yes;
            USB_FEW_INIT_RETRIES = yes;
            ANDROID_BINDER_IPC = yes;
            ANDROID_BINDERFS = yes;
            FS_SYSCTL_PROTECTED_SYMLINKS = yes;
            FS_SYSCTL_PROTECTED_HARDLINKS = yes;
          };

          kernelPatches = [ {
            name = "nitrous-config";
            patch = null;
            extraConfig = ''
              LOCALVERSION ${localversion}
              FS_SYSCTL_PROTECTED_FIFOS 2
              FS_SYSCTL_PROTECTED_REGULAR 2
              KPTR_RESTRICT 1
            '';
          } ];

#          extraMeta.branch = "6.10";
        } // (args.argsOverride or {}));
      linux_nitrous = pkgs.callPackage linux_nitrous_pkg{};
    in
      pkgs.recurseIntoAttrs (pkgs.linuxPackagesFor linux_nitrous);
}

And I include it in my main configuration.nix:
  imports =
    [
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
      ./linux-nitrous.nix
      (import ./home-manager.nix { unstable = unstable; })
    ];

It builds the kernel just fine and installs it as well.
When I reboot and try to boot the kernel, systemd-boot says that it is unsupported.
I know that systemd-boot can only boot EFI executables. You can let the Linux kernel disguise itself as a PE/COFF executable and that way you can boot it as if it was a regular EFI executable.
I checked the configuration that is built when doing nixos-rebuild in the nix store and it does indeed include CONFIG_EFI_STUB=y.
Adding EFI_STUB = yes to structuredExtraConfig or EFI_STUB y in extraConfig (part of kernelPatches) has not yielded any positive result.
Knowing that CONFIG_EFI_STUB has been set, it is only logical that the stub should actually build, but when I use objdump to look at the headers, it can't recognize it.
Here are some commands I ran to analyze the issue:
[root@aludepp:/boot/EFI/nixos]# ls
1bp32vlm6c0g1dg6c2hfi7p1djwkayaw-initrd-linux-6.11-initrd.efi
374x0jd9j96mhayr3nr0w0pdac2nqv14-linux-6.11.0-bzImage.efi
7lpm052fzhzsw2vgb08ghmf54nxibb21-initrd-linux-6.10.9-initrd.efi
ficxfky82d0lyi7kiprpgvgf6md1k803-initrd-linux-6.11.0-initrd.efi
r4mrzns6615l18nfyfqmvbx0cmfzs4s2-linux-6.10.9-bzImage.efi
srvi1yizixvhxhvlb03yhk11agq6h0rb-linux-6.11-bzImage.efi

[root@aludepp:/boot/EFI/nixos]# nix-shell -p binutils --command 'objdump -x 374x0jd9j96mhayr3nr0w0pdac2nqv14-linux-6.11.0-bzImage.efi'
objdump: 374x0jd9j96mhayr3nr0w0pdac2nqv14-linux-6.11.0-bzImage.efi: file format not recognized

[root@aludepp:/boot/EFI/nixos]# nix-shell -p binutils --command 'objdump -x srvi1yizixvhxhvlb03yhk11agq6h0rb-linux-6.11-bzImage.efi'

srvi1yizixvhxhvlb03yhk11agq6h0rb-linux-6.11-bzImage.efi:     file format pei-x86-64
srvi1yizixvhxhvlb03yhk11agq6h0rb-linux-6.11-bzImage.efi
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000103:
HAS_RELOC, EXEC_P, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000af17c2

Characteristics 0x20e
    executable
    line numbers stripped
    symbols stripped
    debugging information removed

Time/Date       Thu Jan  1 01:00:00 1970
Magic           020b    (PE32+)
MajorLinkerVersion  2
MinorLinkerVersion  20
SizeOfCode      0000000000af9000
SizeOfInitializedData   000000000005e000
SizeOfUninitializedData 0000000000000000
AddressOfEntryPoint 0000000000af17c2
BaseOfCode      0000000000005000
ImageBase       0000000000000000
SectionAlignment    00001000
FileAlignment       00000200
MajorOSystemVersion 0
MinorOSystemVersion 0
MajorImageVersion   3
MinorImageVersion   0
MajorSubsystemVersion   0
MinorSubsystemVersion   0
Win32Version        00000000
SizeOfImage     00b5c000
SizeOfHeaders       00001000
CheckSum        00000000
Subsystem       0000000a    (EFI application)
DllCharacteristics  00000100
                    NX_COMPAT
SizeOfStackReserve  0000000000000000
SizeOfStackCommit   0000000000000000
SizeOfHeapReserve   0000000000000000
SizeOfHeapCommit    0000000000000000
LoaderFlags     00000000
NumberOfRvaAndSizes 00000006

The Data Directory
Entry 0 0000000000000000 00000000 Export Directory [.edata (or where ever we found it)]
Entry 1 0000000000000000 00000000 Import Directory [parts of .idata]
Entry 2 0000000000000000 00000000 Resource Directory [.rsrc]
Entry 3 0000000000000000 00000000 Exception Directory [.pdata]
Entry 4 0000000000000000 00000000 Security Directory
Entry 5 0000000000000000 00000000 Base Relocation Directory [.reloc]
Entry 6 0000000000000000 00000000 Debug Directory
Entry 7 0000000000000000 00000000 Description Directory
Entry 8 0000000000000000 00000000 Special Directory
Entry 9 0000000000000000 00000000 Thread Storage Directory [.tls]
Entry a 0000000000000000 00000000 Load Configuration Directory
Entry b 0000000000000000 00000000 Bound Import Directory
Entry c 0000000000000000 00000000 Import Address Table Directory
Entry d 0000000000000000 00000000 Delay Import Directory
Entry e 0000000000000000 00000000 CLR Runtime Header
Entry f 0000000000000000 00000000 Reserved

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .setup        00003000  0000000000001000  0000000000001000  00001000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .compat       00001000  0000000000004000  0000000000004000  00004000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .text         00af9000  0000000000005000  0000000000005000  00005000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  3 .data         00001200  0000000000afe000  0000000000afe000  00afe000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols

[root@aludepp:/boot/EFI/nixos]# file 374x0jd9j96mhayr3nr0w0pdac2nqv14-linux-6.11.0-bzImage.efi
374x0jd9j96mhayr3nr0w0pdac2nqv14-linux-6.11.0-bzImage.efi: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 6.11.0-nitrous3 (nixbld@localhost) #1-NixOS SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1980, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0XA, Normal VGA

[root@aludepp:/boot/EFI/nixos]# file srvi1yizixvhxhvlb03yhk11agq6h0rb-linux-6.11-bzImage.efi
srvi1yizixvhxhvlb03yhk11agq6h0rb-linux-6.11-bzImage.efi: Linux kernel x86 boot executable bzImage, version 6.11.0 (nixbld@localhost) #1-NixOS SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sun Sep 15 14:57:56 UTC 2024, RO-rootFS, swap_dev 0XA, Normal VGA

374x0jd9j96mhayr3nr0w0pdac2nqv14-linux-6.11.0-bzImage.efi is the custom kernel while srvi1yizixvhxhvlb03yhk11agq6h0rb-linux-6.11-bzImage.efi is the original kernel shipped by NixOS.
As you can see, the original one has the EFI stub, but the custom one does not even though the build configuration is based on the original (buildLinux).
On another note, the very same kernel works fine on Arch Linux, also on systemd-boot. So there must be an issue on the NixOS side or in my configuration. On Arch, the nitrous_defconfig is used, and I've tried that on NixOS at first, but it didn't boot the same way which is why I decided to not specify it and instead add the options to structuredExtraConfig instead.
I don't know what else I can try to fix it.

Also, disregard that nitrous3 is different from nitrous4 in the config, I just changed that as I was moving it into the localversion variable. The only other thing that changed was that I removed the EFI_STUB = yes; line as it shouldn't be needed. So the nitrous3 version still had the redundant EFI_STUB config specified in the nix config and that is the one I verified in the nix store.

So funny that my questions are always so hard to find an answer for.

Why is this so hard, why has nobody done this before and why does the NixOS kernel work but when I substitute it with a different kernel source it doesn't? I'm getting a new error now. Lots of error: unused option: ...
